# CefSharp Javascript registration and execution is not working in Release 79.1.36

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, cefsharp

I tried to upgrade CefSharp from Version 69.0.0.0 to 79.1.36. 
I could not get the Javascript interaction working. 
The registration changed from

```
this.Browser.RegisterJsObject
```

to

```
this.Browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register
```

according to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2990.

When I execute EvaluateScriptAsync, I get a response back with Status Canceled.

Trying to understand how to implement it correctly, I examined the CefSharp.WpfExample and noticed that the Javascript functionality in the example WPF application does not work either.
The Execute Javascript (asynchronously) does not do anything when clicking the Run button.
The Evaluate Javascript (Async) returns:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bound is not defined @ about:blank:1:0

Did the Javascript functionality break in the latest release?

*Update*

Here is how it is used in our code.

This is the registration

```
public void RegisterJavaScriptHandler(string name, object handler)
{
    try
    {
        CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
        this.Browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register(name, handler, false, new BindingOptions() { CamelCaseJavascriptNames = false });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

This is the EvaluateScriptAsync part

```
public void InitializeLayers()
{
    try
    {
        int count = _mapLogic.Layers.Count();
        foreach (WMSLayer layer in _mapLogic.Layers)
        {
            if (!_loadedLayers.Contains(layer))
            {
                var script = string.Format("addWMSLayer('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{7}', '{8}', '{9}')",
                    layer.ProviderCode.Url, layer.AttributionText, layer.AttributionHref,
                    layer.Layer, layer.FormatCode.Format, layer.ServerType, layer.Res1, layer.Res2, layer.Res3, layer.Res4);

                var response = this.ECBBrowser.Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                response.ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    count--;
                    if (count == 0) this.initializeMap();

                });
                _loadedLayers.Add(layer);
            }
            else
            {
                count--;
                if(count == 0) this.initializeMap();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

*Update II*

I now believe something has changed with the resource loading.
This is what I have (unimportant parts are left out).

```
public class ECBSchemeHandler : IResourceHandler
{
    private string _mimeType;
    private Stream _stream;

    public bool Open(IRequest request, out bool handleRequest, ICallback callback)
    {
        var result = open(request, callback);
        handleRequest = result;
        return result;
    }

    public bool Read(Stream dataOut, out int bytesRead, IResourceReadCallback callback)
    {
        return read(dataOut, out bytesRead, callback);
    }

    public bool ReadResponse(Stream dataOut, out int bytesRead, ICallback callback)
    {
        return read(dataOut, out bytesRead, callback);
    }

    private bool open(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
    {
        var u = new Uri(request.Url);
        var file = u.Authority + u.AbsolutePath;

        var ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourcePath = ECBConfiguration.DEFAULT_ASSEMBLY_NAMESPACE + "." + file.Replace("/", ".");

        if (ass.GetManifestResourceInfo(resourcePath) != null)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    _stream = ass.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                    _mimeType = ResourceHandler.GetMimeType(fileExtension);
                    callback.Continue();
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            callback.Dispose();
        }           

        return false;
    }

    private bool read(Stream dataOut, out int bytesRead, IDisposable callback)
    {
        callback.Dispose();

        if (_stream == null)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;
            return false;
        }

        //Data out represents an underlying buffer (typically 32kb in size).
        var buffer = new byte[dataOut.Length];
        bytesRead = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        dataOut.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return bytesRead > 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your actual code. To run the qunit tests use the tests -> binding test menu option, if you have first chance exceptions enabled ignore the two exceptions. The default page in the example don't have any objects bound by default.

Comment: @amaitland: I updated the question to include code where the javascript interaction is used.

Comment: On the surface it looks ok, you didn't set `CefSharpSettings.WcfEnabled = true;` as provided in the example, this should be set for you, though no harm in adding it. Past that you've skipped quite a few versions so it's really hard to say what could be happening here, the error you are seeing doesn't actually indicate anything with javascript binding specifically. I'd suggest you use `DevTools` for debugging and start by confirming that basic script execution works. Then work up to more complex. I'd need a full example that reproduce the problem to say anything specific.

Comment: If you enable Legacy javascript binding you can run the tests in the project source https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L208 Make sure you are using the `cefsharp/79` branch. Ignore the first chance exceptions if you have that enabled.

Comment: `LegacyBinding Test` from the Test menu in the WPF example.

Comment: With DevTools I was able to see that not the Javascript Interaction is the problem, but the loading of an embedded resource. With a version 69 of CefSharp the website from the resource is shown in DevTools. With version 79 the website is missing. So there are no javascript methods to call.

Comment: @amaitland: I added Update II to my question with how we do the resource loading. Do you see anything wrong with that?

Comment: I'd suggest using one of the built in options rather than writing your own from scratch https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#resourcehandler

Comment: It is almost working now after refactoring it to use the built-in ResourceHandlers. The requests from the web page are visible in Fiddler. But they all get a 401 Unauthorized response. Our implementation of IRequestHandler's GetAuthCredentials should be called, but it is not.

Comment: Please either close this question and ask a new one or edit this question and provide a detailed example of your problem. Closing and creating a new question is probably best as your problems have nothing to do with JavaScript Binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built-in ResourceHandlers as pointed out by @amaitland solved the problem with the Javascript registration.