# GetAuthCredentials is not called when Authentication is required

Tags: c#, wpf, openlayers, cefsharp

I have a control (ECBControl) that contains the ChromiumWebBrowser

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="_browser" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AllowDrop="True"
  Address="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=Address, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
  FrameLoadStart="_browser_FrameLoadStart" FrameLoadEnd="_browser_FrameLoadEnd" 
  MouseWheel="_browser_MouseWheel"                                             
  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=BitmapScaling, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PreviewKeyDown="_browser_OnPreviewKeyDown"></cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

The dialog (ECBBrowser) that contains the ECBControl registers a map handler

```
private void ECBMapDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ECBBrowser.Browser.RequestHandler = new ECBMapHandler(this);        
}
```

Through some Javascript interaction (that was covered in another SO-Question [CefSharp Javascript registration and execution is not working in Release 79.1.36](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459293/cefsharp-javascript-registration-and-execution-is-not-working-in-release-79-1-36)), a website is called various times to get map images

[image: Fiddler Log]

This where I would expect the GetAuthCredentials of my ECBMapHandler to be called

```
public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
{
    try
    {
        if (isProxy && ECBConfiguration.Instance.ProxyAuthentication)
        {
            var userName = Core.Applications.CoreApplication.ClientCredentials.GetUserName();
            var password = Core.Applications.CoreApplication.ClientCredentials.GetPassword();

            callback.Continue(userName, password);
            return true;
        }

        if (this.Provider.Credentials.TryGetValue(host, out var credentials))
        {
            callback.Continue(credentials.GetUserName(), credentials.GetPassword());
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    callback.Cancel();
    return false;
}
```

But it is never called and as a result the map is not shown in the browser.
What do I need to do to get this to work?

*Update*

I created an example based on the MinimalExample solution.
You can find it at https://github.com/tbremeyer/CefSharpSample.git.
All the action for this example is in MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```
private async Task CallWebSite()
{
    if (_callsPerformed > _maxCalls) return;
    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var resourcePath = "CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf" + ".web.index.html";

    if (executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(resourcePath) != null)
    {
        var resourceStream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePath);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await resourceStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        resourceStream.Close();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        var fileText = await new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEndAsync();
        Browser.LoadHtml(fileText, true);
    }

    var result = await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync($"httpGet('http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/undefined/undefined?accept=json')");
    _callsPerformed++;
}
```

A html file is loaded from a resource file and loaded into the browser. The html contains a script that performs a get request on the url passed as a parameter. The url requires authentication, you get a 401 (as can be seen in Fiddler). The GetAuthCredentials method in the MinimalExampleHandler is never called.

Comment: Start with some basic debugging,  you can use http://httpbin.org/#/Auth to confirm that GetAuthCredentials is working in your code. You can also use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for testing purposes

Comment: @amaitland: I updated my question to include a solution based on the MinimalExample to demonstrate the problem. In previous version of CefSharp this would work and call GetAuthCredentials.

Comment: Can you **fork** the `MinimalExample` please. Then squash your changes into a single commit. Then I can easily see what changes are required to reproduce the problem. I suspect what you are seeing is a result of a newer `CEF/Chromium` version and is not something that can be directly fixed in `CefSharp`, maybe there is a workaround. You can try the latest `81.3.20-pre` release for testing purposes, maybe a newer version of `CEF/Chromium` fixes things. You can use the https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/cefsharp/81 branch for testing purposes.

Comment: @amaitland: I forked the MinimalExample and applied only the changes needed. You can find it at https://github.com/tbremeyer/CefSharp.MinimalExample. I will try version 81.3.20-pre later today.

Comment: Great, much clearer :+1: I'll have a look.

Comment: Version 81.3.20-pre behaves the same way.

Comment: If your example worked with a previous version then it's by pure luck, you call LoadHtml then immediately execute your JavaScript without waiting for the page to load. The LoadHtml(string, bool) overload you are using generates then loads a data uri, performing a cross origin request fails to call GetAuthCredentials on newer version of CEF, might be a bug, might be a stricter CORS policy.

Comment: You can easily workaround this using a different LoadHtml overload. See https://github.com/amaitland/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/223253cc79a2e0d7058d389e91aaaaa32239a253#diff-c9028beae278437ee547316e8f710db4R41 for a modified example, I've also simplified your request handler implementation to help you improve the code you are using.

Comment: @amaitland: Thank you for the work on the MinimalExample solution. Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I was trying to apply the example to our solution. However it seems that I oversimplified the solution. We don't even use LoadHtml. I was able to update the MinimalExample to reflect our solution based on a SchemeHandlerFactory.

Comment: @amaitland: Is there a way to work around the stricter CORS policy in CEF in this scenario?
I updated my fork to represent a very close structural representation of the Unauthorized Response problem with the same web site from the Resource and the same Get request called from Javascript. The repo is still at: https://github.com/tbremeyer/CefSharp.MinimalExample.git.
I will put a word in at my company to get a sponsorship going for you.

Comment: I'll have a look at the updated example and get back to you.

Comment: I had a look at your example and it appears to be working as expected for me. `GetAuthCredentials` is called as expected. If I change the httpbin.org url to http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd then the auth will succeed and I can see the EvaluateScriptAsync call returns the json as expected. The only problem I can see is the httpbin.org url doesn't have the username/password specified, once I change that everything looks ok. Am I missing something?

Comment: @amaitland: Your observation is correct. Since GetAuthCredentials does not get called in my application, I have to investigate whether I can change the API call to include a user and password. Thank you

Comment: Are you using a data uri for your main page? If you are using a scheme handler and adding a cross origin white list entry then it should work. There are instances where the custom scheme behaves differently and you have to switch to using http/https with the scheme handler factory,  just specify a domain name so it only handles a subset of requests, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L174 for example where the scheme handler factory only deals with requests for the fictitious cefsharp.example domain.

Comment: For what it's worth you can rewrite your example to use a UrlRequest and get the response data, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/CefSharp.Test/OffScreen/OffScreenBrowserBasicFacts.cs#L163 you can handle auth requests through http://cefsharp.github.io/api/79.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_IUrlRequestClient.htm

Comment: I am afraid the way the Get Request is performed is not in my hands. A library is used to diplay map data.

Comment: If you have to it's possible to rewrite/override any piece of JavaScript as required. You could replace the whole library with a custom version if required.

Comment: I updated the MinimalExample with the actual library OpenLayers and a sample call to a map service is triggered by adding a layer and adding a view. https://github.com/tbremeyer/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/Unauthorized-Problem 
I don't expect you to fix OpenLayers, but I wanted to show you that GetAuthCredentials is not called in this case and I am not making it up.

Comment: Try adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with value `*` in your schemehandlerfactory see https://gist.github.com/amaitland/d7646b2616c1e7e98c18af9aa64ef8d1#file-schemehandlerfacotry-cs-L9 for an example.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately GetAuthCredentials still does not get called.

Comment: I had a look at https://github.com/tbremeyer/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/Unauthorized-Problem and there's lots of subtle mistakes, not correctly returning the mimType in your scheme handler factory, it cannot load jquery(mismatch in version used and version embedded in assembly). It would be ideal if it could be simplified, there's so much that it would take probably a few hours to actually debug.

Comment: I added the MimeType to the scheme handler factory, fixed the jquery version and fixed some async warnings. The rest I wanted to keep as close as possible to the real application.

Comment: `GetAuthCredentials` does not get called for anything other than the top-level domain. This is the case for Chromium 81-98, I think (and possibly before). Chromium 65 fired `GetAuthCredentials` for any link that requires authentication. Can you elaborate on the `LoadHtml` workaround, or is there a better workaround?